# AngularJS: How to use ng-route when my html template is onepage

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to make my header with ng-repeat:
From something like this:

```
                <ul class="right">
                   <li><a href="#carousel">Início</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#about-us">Sobre</a></li>
                </ul>
```

To this:

```
                    <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
                       <a href="{{item.href}}" ng-click="setActive(item)" ng-class="{active : activeMenu === item}">{{item.texto}}</a>
                    </li>
```

But, since [my template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tohGP.jpg) is one page, the menu is not working anymore. 
Any ideas?

Comment: what do u mean by one page?

Comment: What is in your item's href? does it has the #?

Comment: by onepage I mean the kind of template that I just need to scroll down or click on the menu-button to show my website: https://onepagelove.com/templates/html-templates

Comment: in my href:
scope.menuItems = [
                    {texto: 'Início', href: "#/"},
                    {texto:'Sobre', href: "#sobre"},
                    {texto:'Contato', href: "#contato"},
                    {texto:'Galeria', href: "#galeria"},
                    {texto: 'Trabalhe Conosco', href: "#curriculo"},
                ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any scroll directive to move to different parts of page.

eg: https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll

or enable html5mode which will remove # from url and then you can point to page parts using #